# "by whistling" or "whistling" to answer "How" question

Tags: commas

Given Sentence:

> Trying not to show her sadness, she came into the room, whistling.

Question:

> How did she hide her sadness?

Possible Answers:

> 1. She hide her sadness by whistling.
> 2. She hide her sadness, whistling.

I prefer "2" as "whistling" are used as adverb in this sentence for the two actions happening at the same time.
Which is better, 1 or 2? 
Are there differences in meaning?

Comment: The past tense of **hide** is **hid**.

Answer (score 4):

#1 is definitely the better answer.  #2 doesn't really make sense as an answer.  Let's look at why.

The question here is **how**.  That means "by what method?" or "in what way?"  So the question is asking *by what method* did she hide her sadness, not just "what was she doing when she hid her sadness?"

**By** means "[through the agency or instrumentality of](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by)" (see definition 4a).  Since the question is *by what method*, answer #1, with "by", makes more sense: it means "She hid her sadness *through the method of* whistling."

#2 just says that she hid her sadness and she was whistling.  It doesn't say that whistling was *how* she hid her sadness, so it's not really answering the question.

As a side note, neither answer is completely correct, because they should begin "She **hid** her sadness..."  All of the actions happened in the past: she *came* into the room, she *did* hide her sadness.  That means the answer has to be in the past tense too: She **hid** her sadness.